# What is the correct way to use filledRect()?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm really a beginner at Java. Today I wrote some codes, it should draw some rectangles but they don't. Is there something wrong in my code?

> import java.awt.*;
>
> import java.awt.event.*;
>
> public class NewMain extends Frame{
>
> ```
> static int oldx = 0;
>
> static int newx = 0;
>
> static int oldy = 0;
>
> static int newy = 0;
>
> static Color drawColor = Color.white;
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     Frame myFrame = new Frame();
>
>     Graphics myGraphics = myFrame.getGraphics();
>
>     myFrame.setSize(1360,760);
>
>     myFrame.setTitle("Fun Blackboard");
>
>     myFrame.setVisible(true);
>
>     myFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
>
>     myFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
>
>         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
>
>             System.exit(0);
>
>         }
>
>     });
>
>     myGraphics.setColor(Color.white);
>
>     myGraphics.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
>
>     myGraphics.setColor(Color.lightGray);
>
>     myGraphics.fillRect(0,0,20,40);
>
>     myGraphics.setColor(Color.gray);
>
>     myGraphics.fillRect(0,0,20,60);
>
>     myFrame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
>
>         public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
>
>             System.out.print("X:");
>
>             System.out.print(e.getX());
>
>             System.out.print(", Y:");
>
>             System.out.println(e.getY());
>
>         }
>
>     });
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

I also tried to put them in the mousePressed() thing, but still don't work.

Comment: You are doing many things incorrectly.  The best thing to do is to check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  There are sections in there on how to properly paint.  But I would advise you to learn the basics of Java first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the drawRect of Graphics class, there is an easy method:

```
paint(Graphics g) {
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(5,5,30,30);
g.drawRect(r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height);
}
```

Anyway, awt is dated, you can try creating something with [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/), it's easier and faster to use and it's easier to create a graphical interface